# Content in cell too long for pdf page (NetSuite)

Tags: html, css, netsuite

I hope you can help me with this doubt. To be honest, my knowledge of HTML and CSS is basic. The code I have is for printing a Purchase Order form in PDF.
My form looks and works perfectly fine until somebody has a really long text in a cell. I cannot make the table do a break to the next page when the content in one cell too large. It ends up looking like the image attached.

[page footer with table content over it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2qLd.png)

The PDF document has a margin of 0.5, but it is not taking it into consideration either.

The table is the following

```
 <table align="center" class="itemtable" style="border: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 90%; "><!-- start items -->
<#list record.item as item><#if item_index==0> <!-- items table -->
<thead>
    <tr> <!-- items table: header row -->
    <th align="center">Item</th>
    <th align="center" colspan="2">Description</th>
    <th align="center">Unit Price</th>
    <th align="center">Quantity</th>
    <th align="center">Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead></#if>
<tr> <!-- items table: line item row -->
    <td>${item.item}</td>
    <td colspan="2">${item.description}</td>     <!-- this cell can get too long -->
    <td align="right">${item.rate}</td>
    <td align="right">${item.quantity}</td>
    <td align="right">${item.amount}</td>
    </tr>
    </#list><!-- end items -->
</table>
```

My relevant CSS is the following:

```
<style type="text/css">table {
            font-size: 11pt;
            table-layout: fixed;
        }
td {
        padding: 4px 6px;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    }
table.itemtable th {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Any ideas? Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the BFO PDF library that is used behind the scenes.  Google BFO TD issues should result in the reasons why.  The solution I've found as been to truncate the text

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So there is no workaround in the form, just tell the users to write shorter descriptions?

Comment: Yeah, there is no work around if you have to use a table.  The TD tag is the source of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that is too bad.